# Why my multiprocessing pool is not working? Python

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, multiprocessing, threadpool

here is my code:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import time
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.title('test')
        self.geometry('300x500')
        self.main_ui()
        self.pool = Pool(10)

    def a(self, word):
        print(word, ' start')
        time.sleep(5)
        print(word, 'end')

    def call_a(self, word):
        self.pool.apply_async(self.a, (word,))

    def main_ui(self):
        bnt1 = tk.Button(self, text='a', command=lambda: self.call_a('a'))
        bnt1.place(x=0, y=0, height=100, width=70)
        bnt1 = tk.Button(self, text='b', command=lambda: self.call_a('b'))
        bnt1.place(x=0, y=100, height=100, width=70)
        # pass


def main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

l would like let `print(word, ' start')` and `print(word, ' start')` in other processing without blocking process of tkinter, because `time.sleep(5)` with block process of tkinter. As i think that two process won;t be enough, so i use a processing pool.but the program does not work this time(when i push button, `def a(self,word)` do not work).

the gui can show correctly, but when i push the button, `def a(self, word):` is not working, i don't why and how to fix the problem.

By the way, i'm using python3.

Thank you

Comment: I would expect this to produce errors in the terminal when you click a button - are you simply not looking in the right place?

Comment: @jasonharper sorry i don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Can you give more details about "not working"? An exception?

Comment: @tdelaney when i push the button, the programm will show nothing, i would like to show`a start` and `a finish`, but it donesn't show

Comment: A start and an end? As a popup or something? A GUI generally doesn't have an stdout to write. This is a bit complicated. First, separate the multiprocessing stuff from the GUI class. Maybe just a vanilla function. Then, grab the return from apply_async and create a thread to wait on that for completion. Then have a gui function that knows how to display the result. Finally, post an event back to the gui for that function with the returned data. So, its doable, but with more steps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ignore the return value of `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async`. It's not designed as a fire-and-forget mechanism for running "background" tasks. If you modify your code to check the result:

```
    def call_a(self, word):
        res = self.pool.apply_async(self.a, (word,))
        ret = res.get()
        print("return value:", ret)
```

What you will see when you click on the `a` button is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/gui.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    bnt1 = tk.Button(self, text="a", command=lambda: self.call_a("a"))
.
.
.
TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object
```

So, the problem is that your call to `apply_async` is failing with an exception, but you were never retrieving it.  The failure is caused by the fact that `apply_async` attempts to pickle objects in order to send them to the worker, but that's not possible with a Tk application object.

To make your code work probably requires a some re-architecture: for example, rather than trying to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, consider manually spawning a number of processes (or threads!), and then using a queue to pass data to the workers.

Comment: will i think a multiprocessing Pool is nsseccary in my program. Is think possible wiht tkinter?

Comment: You *can* use a multiprocessing pool, of course. As you've discovered, you can't submit methods on your `Application` class so you will need another class to handle that. As discussed here, you will need to pay attention to return values for things like `apply_async`, so you'll need to figure out how to do that in a way that doesn't impact the interactive aspects of your program.

Comment: @DanhuiXu, Keep in mind that you cannot share pools to child processes. This means that you cannot store the pool as an instance variable since these are all passed implicitly as arguments to child processes whenever you attempt to run an instance method (like `a`) as the target function.